# How to determine whether a class has been loaded by an application loader

Tags: java, jvm

I first retrived the loader of the class, then

loader instanceof sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader

but Eclipse complains the type sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader is not visible.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need to directly use `sun.misc.Lancher.AppClassLoader` (which is vendor specific internal implementation) instead of going through normal ClassLoader class?

Comment: Then how can I know whether a class has been loaded by an application class loader? I am doing some instrumentation and want to only instrument app classes.

Comment: I doubt if you actually need to check the class "has been" loaded or not.  I think what you want to do is whether a class is in the classpath (and hence, "can be" loaded by classloader).  Just get the class you want.  If it can be loaded, then it is in classpath.

Comment: Thanks. I use JVMTI transform hook to instrument classes. But I don't want to touch non-app classes. That is why I need to determine...

Comment: what's the meaning of app or non-app class?  I believe it is base on some characteristic of the class, instead of whether the class "has been" loaded or not.  So I still don't get the reason why you want to use that platform dependent classloader impl

Comment: Have just gone to have a look on the javadoc of `sun.misc.Lancher.AppClassLoader`.  It doesn't looks like that it is providing anything special on top of the Classloader interface (and you cannot determine whether a class "has been loaded or not" from it).  So, what make you unable to use normal ClassLoader interface for your work?